# How Can I setup subdomain on cloudflare

Tags: domain-name-system, subdomain, cloudflare

I have setup my blog [ImNepal.com](http://www.imnepal.com) and it is activated on cloudflare. I want to setup my subdomain i.e.

> [www.sms.imnepal.com](http://www.SMS.imnepal.com) but it got Error 1016 Origin DNS error. What should i do? 
>   I have done like this..
>   1. created subdomain in WHM.
>   2. sms on cname and target.imnepal.com on IP.
>   3. submit.

after that this error 1016 is shown. What should i do? I don't know what to do? It's on Inmotionhosting.

Comment: Subdomains can either use A-Records or CNames. A-Record fires to a specific IP address, and CNames reference other domains. More information here: https://support.dnsimple.com/articles/differences-between-a-cname-alias-url/

Answer (score 0):

sms.imnepal.com and www.sms.imnepal.com are two totally different domains. add cnames for both.

Comment: Thank you Mikael Levoniemi very much... It's been good now.... Now. it's working...